# is there a way to scan multiple projects at sonarqube stage?

Tags: sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube-scan

Correct me if am wrong. I just trying to understand whether is there a way to scan multiple project at sonarqube stage? say i have 10 projects, and the ideal scenario would be to create 10 different jobs and have a 10 different sonar-project.properties file to scan each of them. I was just wondering if there is a way to include all these 10 projects in sonar-project.properties file and then scan them. Sorry if my question was wrong, but trying to explore this sonar stage

Comment: If you have separate build jobs, you need separate SonarQube scans.
Why are you even considering combining them?

Comment: @DavidM.Karr i am having multiple projects and was thinking if i can create one job aggregating all other projects in module basis (by adding module tag in pom) and if sonar can scan all of them with one job. i am not sure if this is possible, but want some inputs if its even possible. My goal is to do static code analyis of all the projects in single run